# How to close ajax loaded page and bring back old content?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm developing a one page portfolio site which will pull projects from separate html files. So, currently I have this code that loads the new URL (specifically the `#project` div) into the current div `#port-content`.

**Part of my custom.js follows:**

```
var hash = window.location.hash.substr(1);
var href = $('.ajax').each(function(){
var href = $(this).attr('href');
if(hash==href.substr(0,href.length-5)){
    var toLoad = hash+'.html #project';
    $('#port-content').load(toLoad)
        }                                           
    });

    $('a.port-more').click(function(){                        
        var toLoad = $(this).attr('href')+' #project';
        $('#port-content').hide('normal',loadContent);
        window.location.hash = $(this).attr('href').substr(0,$(this).attr('href').length-5);
        function loadContent() {
            $('#port-content').load(toLoad,'',showNewContent())
        }
        function showNewContent() {
            $('#port-content').show('normal');
        }
        return false;
    });
```

How can I close this content and bring back my original `#port-content` div. I tried to create a new function doing the opposite but it didn't work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

```
var HTMLstorage = "";
$("#something").on("click", function()
{
var HTMLstorage = $("#someDivWithOldContent").html();
$("#someDivWithOldContent").html(yourNewHTML);
}
```

catch 22 in this is you may lose your handler assignments depending on how you assigned them

Basically capture the HTML before you replace it. Once restoring it, as mentioned, you may need to reassign handlers

Answer (score 0):

Using `.data()` sound like the correct option for this.

```
function loadContent() {
   if(!$('#port-content').data('default')) $("#port-content").data('default', $("#port-content").html());
   $('#port-content').load(toLoad,'',showNewContent())
}
// and create another function to load the default
function loadDefault() {
  $('#port-content').html($("port-content").data('default'));
}
```

Comment: Hi Starx, thank you for your answer, but this broke the function. How would the entire thing look like including a  $('a.close-port').click(function(){ ??

Comment: @user1361999, Put the two function outside the click handler. And create a fiddle if you want me to check it.

Comment: Not sure how to do that with ajax functions.. besides, this function itself has many errors already d.pr/i/x7bJ. Will probably have to hire a jQuery experto to look at this.. Tks anyway.