# changing the content of div by click and change back another click

Tags: html

I want to change the contents of a div using a button click and in another click I want to bring back the old contenns to div I am using a image for button...

My div code is below

```
<div class="pic-container" style="position:absolute; left: 3px; top: 102px;">
<div class="pic-row" >
<img src="images/A.Png" />
<img src="images/B.Png" />     
<img src="images/C.Png" />
<img src="images/D.Png" />
<img src="images/E.Png" />
<img src="images/F.Png" />
<img src="images/G.Png" />
<img src="images/H.Png" />   
<img src="images/I.Png" />
<img src="images/J.Png" />  
<img src="images/K.Png" />   
<img src="images/L.Png" />                    
<img src="images/M.Png" />
<img src="images/N.Png" />
<img src="images/O.Png" />
<img src="images/P.Png" />
<img src="images/Q.Png" />
<img src="images/R.Png" />                       
<img src="images/S.Png" />
<img src="images/T.Png" />
<img src="images/U.Png" />
<img src="images/V.Png" />              
<img src="images/W.Png" />                              
<img src="images/X.Png" />
<img src="images/Y.Png" /> 
<img src="images/Z.Png" />
</div>
</div>
<img  style="position:absolute; left: 272.5px; top: 647px; width: 171px; height: 122.5px;" src="images/Btn_Lower.png"  id="image1" />
```

Please help me to solve this issue

Comment: Did you try anything by yourself?

Comment: Are you using [jQuery](http://jquery.com/)?

Comment: I am a new er one to html so I didn't try and I want to change using javascript or Html please help

Comment: Probably should do a quick search before posting a question:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/5557728/844726   http://stackoverflow.com/a/5557716/844726     http://stackoverflow.com/a/10358031/844726

Comment: I searched and I found nothing

Answer (score 4):

I don't want to confuse you by solving your problem, instead I would like to give you a short and simple example.

You can't achieve it by only using HTML you need javascript.  So here is a way.

1) When you say *content*, it is referred as **innerHTML** in javascript.

2) I think you know about *onclick*, it is called click event.  Similar to that you have a lots of different events in javascript for *keypress, doubleclick*, etc.,

3) Hope you know *ID*, called as ***unique selector***.  Other selector like *class* and you can *HTML5 data-attributes*.

4) To select an element, in JS you can use different methods like,

```
document.getElementById         // select element based on Unique ID
document.getElementsByClassName // select element based on class
document.getElementsByTagName   // select element based on Tag name
```

If you're insterested to learn more about javascript refers [**Mozilla Developers Network**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/)

Here is the shot example I would like to present to you.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="divd">First</div>
<button onclick='changeMe()'>Click It</button>
```

**JS:**

```
function changeMe() {
    var div = document.getElementById('divd').innerHTML;
    if (div === 'First') {
        document.getElementById('divd').innerHTML = "Second";
    } else {
        document.getElementById('divd').innerHTML = "First";
    }
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/2aAJP/)

Comment: I understand the concept sir how can i pass all the div content exactly in my code... I tried to put but shows error can you please shed light on this

Comment: @Saravanakumar Can you explain what you want with your HTML?

Comment: This  **[Mycode](http://jsfiddle.net/shyamsundar055/RD9BT/)**   is my code I tried on your guideline but not worked for me please edit and find out errors